# variance in the polar coordinate

Tags: variance

I am struggle in the variance associated with angle variance. For example, I have

$$\theta= \operatorname{angle}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N r_n e^{i\theta_n} \right),$$

where both $r_n$ and $\theta_n$ are independent variables.

Now how can I obtain the variance associated with $\theta$?

Comment: I tried to update to MathJax. Feel free to correct any of my changes.

Comment: @Galen. Thanks! This format looks nice!

Comment: @Galen, it seems we both were editing simultaneously. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hi @Richard; as you noted, this is a MathJax-enabled site. For a quick start, have a look at [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated)

Comment: Welcome to CV, Richard. Because you pose such a general question, the only suitable answer is "apply whatever formula might be suitable for the distributions."  But if you have specific distributions for $r_n$ and/or $\theta_n$ in mind, the question could have a more specific answer.  As an example, if $r_n$ has positive chance of being exactly zero,  then the average has a positive chance to be zero so $\theta$ isn't even defined in those cases and therefore cannot have a variance.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for your reply! So far, the question I have in mind is that: I have obtained some data points for $r_n e^{i\theta_n}$, from these data points I can easily evaluate $\theta=\sum_n \frac{1}{N}r_n e^{i\theta_n}$. But now I do not know how to evaluate the variance for the angle variance, i.e., from these data points. It seems that the conventional formula $<(x-\bar{x})^2>$ does not work for this situation. Also, assuming that $r_n$ is always positive, do you know any formula to evaluate the variance for the angle defined above.

Comment: I do (I would contemplate using the $r_n^2$ as inverse weights and apply a weighted formula for a circular variance), but haven't the time to test and discuss it.  I know we have fielded similar questions here on CV and I hope you will be able to find a solution given in one of them: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=circular+variance.

Comment: @Richard When you write $\theta = \sum_n \frac{1}{N} r_n e^{i\theta_n}$ do you mean instead $\theta = \text{arg}\left( \sum_n \frac{1}{N} r_n e^{i\theta_n}\right)$? Because your original sum, in the comment above, is not the polar angle.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki, Thanks for pointing this out. I do mean $\theta=\text{arg}(\sum_n \frac{1}{N}r_n e^{i\theta_n})$.